# Show that for any $x∈R^n$, there is $a∈A$ which is closest to $x$ among the points in $A$

Tags: functions, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be a compact set of $R^n$ show that for any $x∈R^n$. Show that for any $x∈R^n$, there is $a∈A$ which is closest to $x$ among the points in $A$, so for any $y∈A$, 
$||y-x||≥||a-x||$.
Hint: fix $x$ and introduce a useful function on $A$, which you show to be continuous, then use a theorem or proposition.

There are actually 3 steps to solve this problem:

1/ I defined the function $f(a)=||x-a||$

2/ I need to show that it's continuous (which is where I'm stuck)

3/ I got to apply the EVT

Comment: There are actually 3 steps to do this problem:

Comment: 1/ I defined the function f(a)=||x-a||
2/ I need to show that it's continuous (which is where I'm stuck)
3/ I got to apply the EVT

Comment: @Arthur - I disagree. The OP already has a working strategy (indicated by the problem itself) and just needs to fill in a gap. Why not stick with this plan?

Comment: @Arthur Unfortunately, we have to use a function.

Comment: Your comment where you described your work so far should be moved to the original post itself.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith all right

Answer (score 0):

Some strategies for proving continuity in your step 2:

A) Write $f(a)$ explicitly as a function of the coordinates of $a$. It is a square root of a sum of some squares of some differences. Note that each of these operations is a continuous function of its inputs, and then invoke a theorem that says that the composition of continuous functions is continuous.

B) Use the triangle inequality and the definition of continuity to prove it directly. Continuity of $f$ would be the statement that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that if $\|a-a'\|<\delta$, then $|f(a) - f(a')|<\varepsilon$. Can you prove this statement using the triangle inequality? (Hint: in this situation the triangle inequality says that

$$ \|x - a'\| \leq \|x - a\| + \|a - a'\| $$

which is the statement that

$$ f(a') \leq f(a) + \|a - a'\|.$$

Let me know if you need a further hint.

Comment: That was really helpful Mr. @Ben.

Comment: for the last part, I used the fact that A is compact and f: A--->R^n is continuous. SO using the EVT there are b,c in A st: f(b)<f(x)<f(c)
But I still can't get how ||y-x||>||a-x||

Comment: You're misquoting the EVT. Since $x$ doesn't lie in $A$, you have no control over how $f(x)$ relates to $f(b)$ and $f(c)$. In fact, as you've defined $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, $x$ is not even in $f$'s domain. What you know from the EVT is that for all $y\in A$, we have $f(b) \leq f(y) \leq f(c)$. (Aside: note $\leq$ not $<$. It has to be $\leq$ because you could take $y=b$ or $c$.) HINT: take $a$ to be your $b$ (the point in $A$ where the minimum value of $f$ occurs). Do you see how to get the needed inequality now?